# Inventory stock is not updating for a particular product using Soap Api

Tags: magento, magento-1.12

I am using Magento version 1.12.0.2.

I am not able to update stock quantity using soap API. It is working fine for other products except one. I tried to update manually from admin and it worked fine but when trying to update from soap API, its not updating.

Please find the script below:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('https://sueryder.wcltest.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('demo', 'demotest');
$result = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate($sessionId, 3711, array(
'qty' => '31',
'is_in_stock' => 1
));
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use soap client- https://sueryder.wcltest.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1 insteed of https://sueryder.wcltest.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl.

Comment: No, it didn't work for this particular product. Because the above code is updating other's product quantity but not to this product. Not even show any error it shows result like int(1) . also i can't see any log for this.